# Is it possible to circumvent ZTE F670L AP/SPI isolation using a network switch and access point combination?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I have a ZTE F670L I got from my ISP (Telecom Egypt). It is lacking, and I can't even disable the AP/SPI Isolation settings because they are hidden.

I have a web server running on my PC (Connected via Ethernet directly to the F670L), and my other devices (Connected via Wi-Fi network from the F670L) cannot access my web server. But, when I create a hotspot connection from my PC to my devices, they can access my web server.

So, I wonder if getting a new switch + Wi-Fi router, connecting the switch to the F670L, and then connecting my PC and the new Wi-Fi router to said switch bypasses AP/SPI Isolation?

Comment: Very likely yes. And you'd only need a 2nd router that you can control.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Would this router (https://www.tp-link.com/eg/home-networking/wifi-router/archer-c86/) in "Access Point" mode suffice?

Comment: I would simply add it to the DMZ of the first router, then it that one disable DHCP and WiFi, then in your own router set those functions.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Oh, so I can't just use the Access Point mode of the new router? I don't want to use all its features, just the Wi-Fi capabilities. Also, did you mean "disable" DHCP and Wi-Fi on the old (ISP) or new (My) router? Thanks.

Comment: In a a nutshell, you'd disable the ISP's router as router and make it a "passtrough" only to yours (pretty much any moderately decent router you can buy will be better in all aspects than the one provided). Then you'd be using yours as a full featured router. I don't understand your fixation in "Acess Point" mode, really.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Sorry, I didn't understand your comment the first time, that's why I repeated "Access Point" multiple times (。_。). Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: "Access Point" mode *would* work, but only for WiFi clients that use the new access point; it's kind of a waste. Using the new router as a full replacement would be more comprehensive.

Comment: @u1686_grawity Ah, I see. Thanks!